# ComboBoxDelegate берущий данные из базы данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, qt, tableview, combobox

[image: Ингредиенты]

[image: Склад]

Есть две таблицы: Склад и Ингредиенты, связанные между собой внешним ключом по `id`. Организовал `ComboBoxDelegate` в `QTableView`. `ComboBox` берет данные из таблицы **Склад** столбца **Вес**. Но тут такой момент, что он отображает полностью весь столбец, а мне нужно, чтобы в каждой строке был выбор "веса" по соответственному айдишнику. На данный момент состояние кода следующее:

```
ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent)
{
    DelegateModel = new QSqlQueryModel;
    DelegateModel->setQuery("SELECT weight FROM sklad, ingridient WHERE
    sklad.idsklad=ingridient.iding;");
}


QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const
QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */, const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);
    editor->setModel(DelegateModel);
    return editor;
}
```

Подскажите кто чем может, а то уже моск сломал как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    // Индекс колонки с идентификаторами ингредиентов.
    const int iding_col = 0;

    const QVariant iding
        = index.model()->data(index.model()
            ->index(index.row(),iding_col));

    if(iding.isValid() == false)
        return Q_NULLPTR;

    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare(
        "SELECT `weight` FROM `sklad`" \
        " WHERE `idsklad` = :idsklad");

    query.bindValue(":idsklad", iding);

    if(query.exec() == false)
        return Q_NULLPTR;

    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);

    // QStyleOptionViewItem содержит множество полезных вещей
    // для построения корректно выглядящего виджета редактора.
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);

    // Каждый раз при создании виджета редактора
    // должен создаваться и новый инстанс модели,
    // поскольку выборка данных различна для каждой из строк.
    // Установка же виджета редактора в качестве родителя модели
    // позволяет не заботиться о своевременном удалении последней.
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel(editor);
    model->setQuery(query);

    editor->setModel(model);

    return editor;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что надо!

Comment: Тут назрел еще один вопрос. Скажем, что я заведу в таблице Склад уникальный ключ. Можно ли как-то получить ключ того элемента, который я выбрал в ComboBox, чтобы потом была возможность редактирования записей через ComboBox?

Comment: Да, можно. Сначала получаете индекс выбранного элемента `QComboBox`, затем из модели, подключенной к нему, по имени колонки получаете уже значение первичного ключа записи. Также, можно использовать классы `QSqlRelation...`, но они не для всех случаев пригодны.

Comment: Я так понимаю это делается в setModelData? Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, с делегатами пока не знаком)

Comment: Да, именно в этом методе делегата.

Comment: Реализовал так: 'int comboRow = combo->currentIndex();
         QModelIndex comboIndex = combo->model()->index(comboRow, 2);
         QVariant value = combo->model()->data(comboIndex);
         QString key = value.toString();' осталось как-то отправить key в класс с tableview

Comment: Вы задайте, лучше, отдельный вопрос, пусть даже он, возможно, будет очень простой, т.к. комментарии, всё же, предназначены для уточнений по текущему.

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите кто чем может, а то уже моск сломал как это сделать

Надо править запрос:

```
SELECT 
  weight 
FROM 
  sklad, 
  ingridient 
WHERE
  sklad.idsklad=ingridient.iding 
  AND
  ingridient.iding = число
```

А "число" вычислять по `QModelIndex`. Я бы в эту сторону копал.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Однако ... могу ошибаться, но у вас с бизнес-логикой немного не так. "Доступно" - не должно быть редактируемо, а должно быть вычислимо, как разница между SUM() продукта на складе, и SUM() использованного. Ну это ИМХО, вам там виднее.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что изначально у меня были просто ячейки с суммой, но по нажатию на кнопку эта сумма должна уменьшаться, а значит надо остаток куда-то записывать и тут у меня возникли проблемы, поэтому решил сделать КомбоБокс. Впринципе это только производственная практика и никуда применяться скорее всего не будет.