# Как отправить переменную из делегата в другой класс?

Tags: c++, qt

В **ComboBoxDelegate.cpp** получаю переменную `key`:

```
void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
     QComboBox *combo = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
     model->setData(index, combo->currentText());

     int comboRow = combo->currentIndex();
     QModelIndex comboIndex = combo->model()->index(comboRow, 2);
     QVariant value = combo->model()->data(comboIndex);
     QString key = value.toString();
     qDebug()<<key;
}
```

Далее хочу отправить её в **pekarnya.cpp**, где буду выполнять с ней следующее:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("UPDATE sklad SET sklad.weight = :weight WHERE sklad.key = :key;");
query.bindValue(":weight", result);
query.bindValue(":key", key);
query.exec();
```

Каким способом можно отправить `key` и оптимально ли это делать?

Связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604559/).

Comment: А `result` откуда берётся? Его также, как и `key` собираетесь передавать?

Comment: Нет, `result` это переменная внутри класса Pekarnya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно оздать собственный произвольный сигнал в делегате, передающий значение ключа, по которому произошли изменения в исходной модели. Достаточно в классе делегата объявить произвольный сигнал и отправлять его из соответствующего метода:

```
class ComboBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        void keyChanged(const QString &key);

    ...
};

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor
    , QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const {

     // Так делать не надо!
     // QComboBox *combo = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);

     // Если речь идёт об указателе, связанном с QObject или QWidget,
     // используйте именно qobject_cast<T>().
     QComboBox *combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox>(editor);
     if(combo == Q_NULLPTR) return;

     model->setData(index, combo->currentText());

     int comboRow = combo->currentIndex();
     QModelIndex comboIndex = combo->model()->index(comboRow, 2);
     QVariant value = combo->model()->data(comboIndex);

     emit keyChanged(value.toString());
}
```

На приёмной стороне или, проще говоря, слоте, который будет предварительно подключен к данному сигналу, останется лишь выполнить соответствующую обработку:

```
void Pekarnya::onSkladKeyChanged(const QString &key) {
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare(
        "UPDATE sklad SET sklad.weight = :weight" \
        " WHERE sklad.key = :key;");

    query.bindValue(":weight", result); // "result" берётся извне.
    query.bindValue(":key", key);
    query.exec();
}
```

---

От себя я бы всё-таки порекомендовал отойти от такой практики синхронизации взаимосвязей между таблицами на уровне кода в приложении и по возможности переключить ответственность за отслеживанием изменений непосредственно на саму базу данных. Это могут быть триггеры или даже процедуры. Также, в отдельных простых случаях помогает упростить задачу использование связки уже готовых классов `QSqlRelation...`.

**Замечание**

Поскольку метод `ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData() const` является константным, соответственно, чтобы отправить из него сигнал `ComboBoxDelegate::keyChanged()` потребуется или объявить и сам сигнал константным:

```
signals:
    void keyChanged(const QString &key) const;
```

Или произвести приведение типа указателя `this` к неконстантному типу:

```
ComboBoxDelegate *delegate = const_cast<ComboBoxDelegate*>(this);
emit delegate->keyChanged(value.toString());
```